# SQL Server 2014 with compatibility Level 100 return -1 when call to LastIndexOf in CLR function

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have an existing `CLR` function that is working fine in SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2012 (DB compatibility level 100). However, when I put it in SQL Server 2014 with same DB compatibility level, I get an error when execute the function.

This is the error message I get.

> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Procedure spGetNextEventName, Line 18
>   A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "GetNextEventName":
>   System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Length cannot be less than zero.
>   Parameter name: length
>   System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException:

This only occurs when the DB compatibility is 100 and lower. If I set the DB compatibility level to 110 and above, the function is working fine.

Unfortunately I cannot change the DB compatibility level.

I am trying to find out which line of code in the CLR function that causes this problem, and at the end, I found out this is because of the result from `LastIndexOf` is incorrect, when the DB compatibility level is 100 and below.

The SQL Server version is :

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4100.1 (X64) 
Apr 20 2015 17:29:27 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Enterprise Evaluation Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)
```

and installed is Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard.

To show the problem I have with the `LastIndexOf`, I have written another simple CLR function. The project target platform is SQL Server 2008.

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read)]
public static SqlString GetNextEventName(SqlString eventName)
{
    if (eventName.IsNull)
        return new SqlString("empty value");

    var c1 = new Class1();
    string result = c1.TestIndexOf(eventName.Value);

    return new SqlString(result);
}
```

The `Class1` is in another class library. The project target framework is .NET Framework 3.5.

```
public class Class1
{
    public string TestIndexOf(string value)
    {
        var index = value.LastIndexOf(value);
        var dotNetVersion = System.Environment.Version.ToString();

        return string.Format("Value: {0} | Index: {1} | .Net Version: {2}",
            value,
            index,
            dotNetVersion);
    }
}
```

and call the function below in the SSMS.

```
SELECT [dbo].[JustTest] ('(a)')
```

And I get this result:

```
Value: (a) | Index: -1 | .Net Version: 4.0.30319.34209
```

It failed to find the last index of (a). Weird.

If I change the DB compatibility to 110, I get the correct answer as below:

```
Value: (a) | Index: 0 | .Net Version: 4.0.30319.34209
```

I created another console application that using the same class library and call the same function with same parameter passed in, and I get the same problem.

How can I make it work in SQL Server 2014 with the DB compatibility level of 100?

Comment: The output of the simple function should be a hint - it shows **.Net Version: 4.0** - you need to target **.NET 4.0** with SQL Server 2014 - not .NET 3.5. Can you try to have all your code target **.NET 4.0** in your simple example, and see if that runs afterwards?

Comment: I have tried target the SQL Server Project to SQL Server 2014 and the Class Library to .Net 4.5, unfortunately I still get the same result.